# Why doesn't HttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers contain the headers associated with the request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API application that we forward the HttpRequestMessage.Content to other methods that process the request. One of the set of values that is needed is the Headers that are sent as part of the request.

When I look at HttpRequestMessage.Headers.headerStore, I see all the headers sent to the request. But when I look at HttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.headerStore, I only see a few of default headers.

Why doesn't HttpRequestMessage.Content.headerStore contain all the headers associated with the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request headers and content headers have different purposes.

While request headers carry information about request itself and about client (caller), content headers describe "entity" or its metadata.

Have a look at sample http request:

```
            POST /some/url HTTP/1.1
            Host: someHost
            User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36
request     Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
headers     Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
            Connection: keep-alive
            Referer: url
            Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------564564546545645
            Content-Length: 462560

            ------------564564546545645
content     Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.png"
headers     Content-Type: image/png

            .PNG
            ......................;
            ------------564564546545645
```

Comment: This is according to [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-42)